# Integration test: test the Autowired annotation

Tags: spring, testing, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to test injection dependencies in spring.

I have a Class:

```
 public SomeClass {
   @Autowired
   SomeBean bean ;
   public SomeBean getBean(){
     return this.bean ;
   }
 }
```

I want a test like this:

```
public SomeClassTest {
  SomeClass someClass ;
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    someClass = new SomeClass() ;
  }                              
  @Test public testBeanWired(){
    assertNotNull(someClass.getBean()) ;                                                  
  }                          
}
```

I have tried with the ContextConfiguration with a test configuration file, but the test fails, i don't want to use @Autowired in the test, i want to create an instance of my class and the bean is autowired automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only possible if the bean is annotated with @Configuration and if the byte-code is instrumented. Otherwise, only beans created by Spring are autowired. Not beans created using `new`. Because Spring has no way to know that you created an object and that it must inject a dependency in it.

That's a fundamental principle of dependency injection: the objects are instantiated and injected by the container, not by you.

Comment: That's what i want to test, is the container doing its job ? i have a context configuration file for my test, where the bean is declared, i want when my class is instantiated, the bean to be injected, in the test..

Comment: The job of the container is to autowire beans that the container instantiates. You're testing if it autowires beans that you instantiate. So the test will fail. Not because the container isn't doing its job, but because you use new instead of getting a bean instance from the Spring context.

Comment: mmmmm right, so i just have to mark `@Autowired SomeClass someClass` and the test will pass, and yes it pass.